# Can’t access an aspx page via IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

I’m running IIS 5 on Windows XP professional

I created new Web project and configured VS 2008 to save this application to 
location c:\Inteput\wwwroot. Thus VS saved the project into directory:

```
c:\Inteput\wwwroot\WebApplication1
```

I then transformed this WebApplication1 folder into virtual directory (this virtual directory is also configured as web application). But whenever I try to access:

```
c:\Inteput\wwwroot\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\default.aspx
```

through browser using URL:

```
http://localhost/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/default.aspx
```

, I get an exception saying:

> Configuration Error 
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

BTW - Virtual directory does have *Read* and *Run scripts* permissions set

Q2 - How do I configure Visual studio to run Web app via IIS and not via integrated web server? Thus so that when I’d press CTRL+F5, the browser would be server a page by IIS and not by integrated web server?

thank you

Comment: InetPub and I'm sorry for not noticing your reply

Answer (score 1):

You say it is running as an application - is is using the right ASP.NET version? (2.x)

Re debugging in IIS; you do that on the project properties - on the Web panel I believe; change it to "Use Local IIS Web Server" and enter the url to the application root on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you followed a strange (wrong) procedure, for reference create a small project and point to a (new) virtual dir right from the New Project dialog. This gives you a check (IIS 5 is kind of old) and a project to compare.

And/or create a virtual dir and deploy the project to it using the Web Publishing or Web Copy tools.

From the face of it, it looks like you've got one WebApplication1 folder to many in your URL. That rimes with the error, certain web.config settings are only allowed in an Applications root.

Added: regarding Q2, when you set IIS for debugging you will also have to configure the output directory as a Virtual Dir. This is normally done during Project creation by VS.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem with you `web.config`, can you please supply yours? Have you got more that one?

I've had an error like this one before, it doesn't quite fit what you are saying, but maybe you left out some details.

Basically if you have an application, you should not configure the `MachineToApplication` settings in `web.config`'s in the subdirectories. Although I suppose other things can make this error turn up.

Oh I bet you do have two web.configs

here `c:\Inteput\wwwroot\WebApplication1\web.config`

and here `c:\Inteput\wwwroot\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\web.config`

Answer (score 0):

1 - It works now. I created new virtual directory

```
c:\Inteput\wwwroot\Testing
```

and copied everything from

```
c:\Inteput\wwwroot\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
```

into this new directory, so that now *web.config* was in the root directory of an application.

A)

> certain web.config settings are only allowed in an Applications root.

So was that my *web.config* one that is only allowed in Application root? How can I know for sure?

2 -

> Re debugging in IIS; you do that on the project properties - on the Web panel I believe; change it to "Use Local IIS Web Server" and enter the url to the application root on localhost.

Found it, but now I get the following error:

> Access is denied. 
>   Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources.
>
> Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to 'C:\Documents and Settings\kaja\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\Default.aspx'.

thanx